# Should rpc.statd write anything into wtmp?

Tags: login, nfs, remote, statistics

On several linux machines (some old custom variant of gentoo) I have huge wtmp files, up to gigabyte in size. After some experiments I know that there is `rpc.statd` daemon running on all servers and there is monitoring running with [`rup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rup) command. Monitoring server runs rup every minute with list of all machines; so statistics are collected.

After each run of `rup` the `wtmp` file is getting bit larger.

My question: Should rpc.statd update wtmp and what will it write into wtmp? My `last` command does not extract anything about `rup`, `rpc.statd` from wtmp.

Comment: Ok, I have sources of some version of `rpc.statd` here: [sources.debian.net/src/nfs-utils/1:1.2.8-6/utils/statd](http://sources.debian.net/src/nfs-utils/1:1.2.8-6/utils/statd) but I can't find actual utmp/wtmp writes.

Comment: Is there an `su` command running every minute, too? Maybe from crontab? Some versions of su make entries in wtmp.

Comment: Mark, there are 5 servers with rpc.statd running. And also there is 1 monitoring desktop with cron task of `rup server1 server2 ...server5`. The communication is done via RPC. There is RPC daemon rpc.statd, registered in portmapper). There is no su and no crontasks on servers.

Comment: The `last` command will display `wtmp` entries. If you run `last|more`, does that show any user or host name or subsystem that may help you determine what's writing to it?

Comment: Also, creation of a terminal window will add an entry to `wtmp`. Is anything creating and closing terminal windows every so often?

Comment: Mark, rup is started remotely, handled by `rpc.statd` daemon, without any terminal creation. `last` have no info about `rup` or `rpc.statd` - rechecked by deleting wtmp and doing 10 accesses by `rup` - no 10 lines was printed by last.

Comment: Can you run `strace -o logfile -f -p pid` to trace `rpc.statd` to see what files it writes to? Is there an `rpc.rstatd` running, too? `rpc.rstatd` is usually what responds to `rup` requests. `rpc.statd` is for NFS locking.